# Roots of a quintic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I find the roots of a quintic equation. However my original question is what is the sum of the roots of $x^5+3x^2+7=0$.

Comment: the sum of the roots is zero.

Comment: For finding the sum of the roots of general polynomials [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas) are useful

Answer (score 5):

The roots do not need to be found explicitly.

**Hint**:

Suppose the polynomial factors as $f(x) = (x-a_1)(x-a_2) \cdots (x-a_5)$.  Now, if you were to expand this, what is the coefficient on the $x^4$ term?

---

Notice that the constant term also has an interesting piece of information.  In general, the coefficients on these terms are [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) evaluated at the roots.

Comment: Not that it matters here, but that coefficient would be the sum of the roots *counting multiplicities* ;-)

Comment: Indeed, that's a good point to make @dxiv.  Even without finding the roots explicitly, one can check whether $f$ has repeated roots by computing $\gcd(f, f')$.